# Finding a deleted question without enough rep

Tags: support, specific-question, reputation, search, deleted-questions

I'm asking here a similar question to [this one](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4432/16035).

> I'm pretty sure I've asked a question a while ago (years?) about the **use of ammonia in agriculture** where it is introduce directly into the soil. The question included a photo of a very large tank being drawn by a tractor in a field being treated.
>
> I can't find it now though, and I wonder if it might have been automatically deleted for no activity.
>
> If I had enough rep, I could type `user:27918 deleted:1` and see all of my deleted questions, but I don't, so I can't.
>
> Is there any other way I can retrieve the text and links in the question, provided that I'm right and I did ask it here?
>
> I'm trying to see if information or links from this question can also be helpful in my recent question [How can agricultural ammonia lead to PM2.5 production in the atmosphere?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/16627/6031)

I also don't have enough rep on this site to use the `user:27918 deleted:1` function. is it possible to check for the described question here as well?

Comment: I don't see a deleted question of yours about ammonia or agriculture. You deleted a single post ("How will the safety concerns be resolved regarding data distribution as DNA?") 2 years ago.

Comment: @theforestecologist okay thank you very much for checking! I'll think on this further; shall I leave this question here or just delete it? You're welcome to convert your comment to an answer and I can accept it also.

Comment: it's a valid question, so I don't mind leaving it. Good luck!

Comment: @theforestecologist and it turned out to have an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Mystery solved.

@ Tyberius' [answer](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4434/16035) (in Chemistry meta) points out that my question exists here in Biology SE, *but that it was not deleted.*

I'd searched my questions in Chemistry, then asked for help searching my deleted questions in Chemistry, then searched here in Biology, then asked for help searching deleted questions here in Biology, but my searching of my undeleted questions here never returned this question.

The only explanation for that that I can think of is my tendency to mis-spell ammonia with one "m" instead of two. The SE [spelling suggestion bot](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/920/12102) doesn't return "Did you mean **ammonia?**" when you search for the miss-spelled `amonia`.

Thanks to everyone for your help!

The never-was-missing-in-the-first-place question in question is [Why do soil bacteria produce nitrous oxide as a result of anhydrous ammonia fertilizer application?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/65163/27918)

> [image: no suggested spelling]